# A field theory problem which is in fact a group theoretic problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

[image]

I am doing this exercise in Milne's notes and I think it is quite a general stuff so the result would be very useful. But the proof is omitted and the author only left with a sentence:

> This is really a group theory problem disguised as a ﬁeld theory problem.

So may I please ask what is the core of the problem? I had tried to convert it to a group theoric problem but so far I have not solved it. May I please ask for an answer. Or any reference would also be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sylow's theorems.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Actually I have not learnt about it. So is there any elementary approach?

Comment: Man, this screams Sylow theorems.  That's unfortunate.

Comment: This is just basic group theory (Sylow theory as already mentioned). I think if you knew the Sylow theory, this would be easy for you. And since you'll be learning Galois groups etc., why not learn some basic group theory? Even the hint suggests treating this as a group theory problem.

Comment: Use Sylow theorems and the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory #grouptheory #galoistheory

Comment: also @non-abeliangroupoforder9 , you don't exist ;)

Comment: I learnt some group theory some time ago and I would read it. Thanks to you all who leave comments.

Comment: @cat Yeah, this is a surprising result proved in the exercise when I was learning group theory and I find it very interesting.

Comment: Chiming in. I am more or less certain that the exercise is to be done with Sylow theory. Or, cannot be solved without. IIRC Milne maintains reasonably accurate lists of interdependencies both within and between his course notes. Did you check?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If one wants to do it without Sylow Theorems, the hardest part seems to be the existence of a subgroup $P$ with $p^2$ elements. Once one has that, the rest is fairly automatic even without those congruence relations from the Sylow Theorems, **if** one is willing to use two things: (i) $P$ is automatically normal, since its index is the smallest prime divisor of the group order. (ii)There is some element of order $q$ by Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: Agreed @MooS. The amount of Sylow theory needed here is rather minimal. I seem to have exaggerated a bit :-)